# Use nodejs module in java (graalvm, missing crypto)

Tags: javascript, java, cryptography, graalvm

I'm writing a java client for a specific application. There is already a library for communication with application, a npm module written in JavaScript for node.js and also a web variant compiled using webpack. The npm module is to complex to rewrite it using java, therefore I'm looking for a solution to execute it from java code directly.

I tried to do it using GraalVM embedded in java, as an Script-Engine. The problem what I'm facing is the npm lib **get-random-values**. This library uses either **window.crypto.getRandomValues** if executed in browser or **require("crypto").randomBytes** if executed in node.js environment.

Graalvm does not have window.crypto.getRandomValues obviously, either does not know **require** and there is no **require("crypto").randomBytes**.

is there a pure js implementation of getRandomValues  or randomBytes? Or may be it possible to call eg. java implementation **SecureRandom.generateSeed** from javascript as replacement of window.crypto.getRandomValues?

Thanks

Update:

just investigated the way to call SecureRandom.

I created js file with the following content

```
var SecureRandom = Java.type('java.security.SecureRandom');

var window = {
    crypto: {
        getRandomValues: (buf) => {
            //print("buf_length", buf, buf.length);
            var bytes = SecureRandom.getSeed(buf.length);
            buf.set(bytes);
        }
    }
};
```

imported it, and it seems to be working. Now I'm able to load browser version of the npm module without any errors. There are still some problems, but not to much critical.

Comment: I'd look at [GraalVM -> Java interop](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/js/JavaInteroperability/). However, beware that you should be using `new SecureRandom()` and then create an array and use `nextBytes` on it, and of course then copy it into `Uint32Array`. I'm however not a GraalVM user, so the techniques are yours to discover.

Comment: Yes, polyfilling `window` is the right approach. Graaljs is a JS engine, when you embed it in a java app it doesn't offer the node API. (there's a node implementation you can use with the API and call into your java app, but it's much more cumbersome). All in all -- most calls indeed are just a few lines of java.